# Plsql procedure using cursor to insert record

Tags: for-loop, plsql, duplicates, cursor

I have to write a procedure in plsql to read data row by row using cursor and if any duplicate record then mark it as duplicate in stg table...can anyone help me  to write procedure to select data from stg table and then check if any duplicate row by row and then insert valid record.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example.

There are a handful of ways to do this.

```
-- Create test table
create table stg ( id number, is_dup varchar2(1) );

-- Insert data with dups
insert into stg ( id ) values ( 1 );
insert into stg ( id ) values ( 1 );
insert into stg ( id ) values ( 2 );
insert into stg ( id ) values ( 3 );
insert into stg ( id ) values ( 4 );
insert into stg ( id ) values ( 5 );
insert into stg ( id ) values ( 4 );

-- Check data
select * from stg;

        ID I
---------- -
         1
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5
         4

7 rows selected.
```

The approach using CURSOR would be:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c1 IS
      SELECT id, COUNT(1) nc
      FROM stg
      GROUP BY id;
BEGIN
   FOR r1 IN c1 LOOP
     IF r1.nc = 1 THEN
        -- Insert valid
        INSERT INTO tab ( cols ) 
        SELECT cols
        FROM stg
        WHERE id = r1.id;
     ELSE
        -- Update dup
        UPDATE stg SET is_dup = 'Y' WHERE id = r1.id;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
END;
/
```

I prefer the set based approach:

```
-- apply UPDATE to mark duplicates with Y
update stg s
set s.is_dup = 'Y'
where s.id in ( select s2.id from stg s2 group by s2.id having count(1) > 1 )

4 rows updated.

--Check again - ids 1 and 4 should be marked as duplicates
select * from stg;

        ID I
---------- -
         1 Y
         1 Y
         2
         3
         4 Y
         5
         4 Y

7 rows selected.

   -- Now insert 
   INSERT INTO tab ...
   SELECT ....
   FROM stg
   WHERE is_dup IS NULL;
```

Comment: I have 2 columns in my stg table product_id and country I have to check each time the product_id and country while inserting record into master table.I'm not able to insert record into master as one product id is mapped to multiple countries...so it would be helpful if anyone can help me to check each product_id combination one by one and then insert the record into master table

Comment: You need to provide the stg and master table definitions, and sample data if you want a answer specific to your issue. The above answer give generic guidance, based on the uniqueness being on the `id` column. Where is see `id` in my answer you can extend it to more than one column as teh logic will hold.